# How can I make this counter work perfectly?

Tags: javascript

I already asked before two times(I'm sorry) but I didn't like the old approach and I think this one is better. I'm making a connect four game with a score (not ending when the player connects four colors) I want to add to the class of the four connected colors `winh` to not start the win function again. if I didn't do that: 4 colors --> 1 score; 5 colors --> 2 score ... because the `counter == 4`. I want 4 colors --> 1 and other 4 colors --> 1.

here's the code:

```
function horizontalWin(row, col) {
    var playervalue = avatar[turn];
    var count = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < GRID_SIZE; i++) {
        var slot = document.getElementById('tbl').rows[row].cells[i].innerHTML;
        var slotclass = document.getElementById('tbl').rows[row].cells[i];
        if (slot == playervalue && !slotclass.classList.contains('winh')) {
            count++;
            slotclass.classList.add('winh');
            if (count == 4) {return true;}
        }
        else {count = 0;}
    }
    return false;
}
```

the counter only stays at 1.

Comment: Try comment "else" line and try again. If it works like expected, you need adjust your code, beause you are reseting counter to 0.

Comment: no, the counter is still 1

Comment: Add a console log inside "if" and inside "else", and you can see how many time entered in each condition. I'm just guessing, the counter can be one, because in last past, entered the "if".

Comment: I did that, console.log(count) //  it's always 1

Comment: It's a little hard to help without all code. Start debug the code. ``console.log(GRID_SIZE); console.log(slot); console.log(slotclass); console.log(counter);``

Comment: `console.log(GRID_SIZE); // 15` `console.log(slot)// it changes and it have 15 values from the row of the table` `console.log(slotclass)// it changes and it have 15 values too` `console.log(count)// always 1`** thanks a lot by the way**

Comment: Put a alert after ``count++;``-> ``alert(count);`` and a ``alert(count);`` after count = 0; in else.

Comment: it alerts 0, and when I add a color it alerts 1 for just a second and it goes to 0 again

Comment: Something are wrong outside of this context. Sorry, but i can't help more.